# How can I log request/response headers with IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, owin, iis-express

Is it possible to load request and response headers when using IIS Express?

Comment: if your application is MVC based, how about using filtering feature, to capture all responses and requests: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513%28VS.98%29.aspx

Comment: It isn't. That's why I need this logging functionality.

Comment: I assume you do that for debug purposes. In that case I use; Fiddler tool to trace my request and responses. Not only for IIS express actually, but all traffic going in-out into my development server.

Comment: Great suggestion! Yes, that's been the answer I was looking for. I was digging at the wrong end. Trying to debug OAuth2 authentication. IIS logs wouldn't have been sufficient here. After running a Fiddler debugging session, I've now got all the information I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who might be interested in the answer to my question:

Downloading Fiddler is the answer. It acts as a web proxy and logs all the traffic there.